# How to get redirect URI and a token from the redirected url in android

Tags: java, android

I have never implemented the redirected URI or Url. These things are new to me. I need to implement it for SSO in my apps.
 Please guide me the right way, some codes can help me out.
 I prefer code than description

Answer (score 0):

Following code will help you to retrieve the parameter From your url

```
String url = "http://domain.com/page?parameter1=value1&parameter2=value2";
List<NameValuePair> parameters = URLEncodedUtils.parse(new URI(url));
for (NameValuePair p : parameters) {
    System.out.println(p.getName());
    System.out.println(p.getValue());
}
```

in above code you can check if getName returns token then perform your operation accordingly.

Comment: you just missed th emain part which is how to register the activity for redirect URI and get the URL without browser just like facebook @Anjali